# Node Express: Send only custom error messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Somehow I'm getting mongo errors being sent to the front end, I'm expecting just the error message to be sent that I'm throwing from `throw new Error('Database failed to save');`

```
  static join = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
      const { email, password, fullName } = req.body;
      const confirmationCode = randomBytes(20).toString('hex');
      const alreadyRegistered = await userModel
        .findOne({ 'shared.email': email })
        .exec();
      if (alreadyRegistered) throw new Error('You have already registered');
      const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
      if (!hash) throw new Error('Failed to hash password');
      const user = new userModel({
        email: { confirmationCode },
        password: { hash },
        shared: { email, fullName },
      } as UserModelInterface);
      const saved = await user.save();
      if (!saved) throw new Error('Database failed to save');
      const jwtToken = jwt.sign(
        { email: saved.shared.email, id: saved._id },
        process.env.JWT_SECRET
      );
      if (!jwtToken) throw new Error('JWT failed to generate');
      const sent = await Email.confirmEmail(
        saved.shared.fullName,
        saved.shared.email,
        saved.email.confirmationCode
      );
      if (!sent) throw new Error('Email failed to send');
      res.status(200).send({ data: saved.shared, jwtToken });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(400).send({ error }); // <== How to only return the mesage in the throw statement??
    }
  };
```

Comment: res.status(400).send({ error: error.message }); did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error object includes a property what called `message`, the property is string value which is message you pass to create a new error object.

If you just want to return a string to client when your logic code get back an error, just return the error message.

```
res.status(400).send(error.message || 'Something went wrong!');
```

Or you can send to client a json object, like the way when server response with http status is 200

```
res.status(400).send({message: error.message || 'Something went wrong!'});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code:

```
static join = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
   try {
      const { email, password, fullName } = req.body;
      const confirmationCode = randomBytes(20).toString('hex');
      const alreadyRegistered = await userModel
         .findOne({ 'shared.email': email })
         .exec();

      if (alreadyRegistered) 
        throw new Error({status:400, customMessage: "You have already registered" });

     const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
     if (!hash) 
        throw new Error({status:400, customMessage: 'Failed to hash password' });

     const user = new userModel({
        email: { confirmationCode },
        password: { hash },
        shared: { email, fullName },
     } as UserModelInterface);

     const saved = await user.save();
     if (!saved) 
       throw new Error({status:400, customMessage:'Database failed to save'});

     const jwtToken = jwt.sign(
        { email: saved.shared.email, id: saved._id },
        process.env.JWT_SECRET
     );

     if (!jwtToken) 
        throw new Error({status:400, customMessage:'JWT failed to generate'});

     const sent = await Email.confirmEmail(
        saved.shared.fullName,
        saved.shared.email,
        saved.email.confirmationCode
     );

     if (!sent) 
        throw new Error({status:400, customMessage: 'Email failed to send' });

     res.status(200).send({ data: saved.shared, jwtToken });
  } catch (error) {
     const { status: 500, customMessage=null  } = error || {};
     res.status(status).send({ error: customMessage || "Internal Server Error"  });
  }
};
```

Hope you problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

Try this way you can return your error message.I hope it will helps you.

```
 static join = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
      const { email, password, fullName } = req.body;
      const confirmationCode = randomBytes(20).toString('hex');
      const alreadyRegistered = await userModel
        .findOne({ 'shared.email': email })
        .exec();
      if (alreadyRegistered) throw new Error('You have already registered');
      const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
      if (!hash) throw new Error('Failed to hash password');
      const user = new userModel({
        email: { confirmationCode },
        password: { hash },
        shared: { email, fullName },
      } as UserModelInterface);
      const saved = await user.save();
      if (!saved) throw new Error('Database failed to save');
      const jwtToken = jwt.sign(
        { email: saved.shared.email, id: saved._id },
        process.env.JWT_SECRET
      );
      if (!jwtToken) throw new Error('JWT failed to generate');
      const sent = await Email.confirmEmail(
        saved.shared.fullName,
        saved.shared.email,
        saved.email.confirmationCode
      );
      if (!sent) throw new Error('Email failed to send');
      res.status(200).send({ data: saved.shared, jwtToken });
    } catch (error) {
     return res.status(400).json({ message:'write your message here' }); // change this line
    }
  };
```

Comment: I don't want to hardcode an error message I want to only send the message from the throw statement